# Non fundamental point with local ring integrally closed is necessarily regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

This is related to a comment made in Mumford Algebraic Geometry I, Complex Projective Geometry.

> "... in fact every $x\in X$ which is not fundamental and where $O_{x,X}$ is integrally closed in $\Bbb C(X)$ is actually a regular point."

$X$ above is a projective variety and $\Bbb C(X)$ denotes function field of $X$ over complex number. Assume $X,Y$ projective varieties s.t $f:X\to Y$ is a dominant rational map. The set of points of $x\in X$ s.t. fiber of $f(x)$ with codimension $>\dim(X)-\dim(Y)$ is called fundamental. It is clear that fundamental points are closed.

Regular local implies UFD which implies integrally closed.

$\textbf{Q:}$ How is not being fundamental and local ring integrally closed related to regularness?

Comment: What is the condition on $Y$? I am confused about the case of $f$ being the identity map.

Comment: @Youngsu $Y$ is a projective variety. There is no further requirement. If $f:X\to X$ is identity, then there are no fundamental points. So in this case, the map is smooth away from singularity points. However, smooth points' local ring are automatically regular. So I guess the other way to ask a question is how this is related to smoothness of $x\in X$. If $x\in X$ is a smooth point, then it is clearly regular. However, I do not see this is necessarily.

Comment: This is clearly false - consider any nonsmooth normal variety and the projection to a point. Perhaps you are missing an assumption.